# JS/CSS Overlay : how to differentiate 2 buttons on same page?

Tags: javascript, css, overlay

I am working on a site where I employ the Overlay effect. I found how to do it on W3 Schools and it's quite easy.

However, I am trying to have two separate overlays on the same page: click on one button to see one set of text, click on a second to see another.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to differentiate the separate overlays. In my example below, if a user clicks on the first overlay button, then get the text meant for the second overlay. And if they click on the second overlay button they get the text meant for the second overlay. I can't seem to get the first overlay text to appear, in other words.

I imagine it is something fairly simple but I haven't figured it out on my own.

Below is some code. This is not my actual site, but a slightly edited version of what's offered on W3. If I could learn how to differentiate the two buttons here I can do it on my own site.

Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSS -->
<style>
#overlay1 {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay2 {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Overlay 1: -->
<div id="overlay1" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">Overlay 1 Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay with Text Examples</h2>
  <button onclick="on()">Overlay 1</button>
</div>

<script>
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "none";
}
</script>




<!-- Overlay2: -->
<div id="overlay2" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">Overlay 2 Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <button onclick="on()">Overlay 2</button>
</div>

<script>
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the same `on` and `off` functions for both overlays... In other words, you are redefining the functions.

Change your `body` to the following:

```
<!-- Overlay 1: -->
<div id="overlay1" onclick="off('overlay1')">
  <div id="text">Overlay 1 Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay with Text Examples</h2>
  <button onclick="on('overlay1')">Overlay 1</button>
</div>

<!-- Overlay2: -->
<div id="overlay2" onclick="off('overlay2')">
  <div id="text">Overlay 2 Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <button onclick="on('overlay2')">Overlay 2</button>
</div>

<script>
function on(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

function off(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```